# Operador 'mayor que' y 'menor que' en batch

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, script

Amigos, tengo el siguiente script, el cual desarrollé como un simple ejercicio, no obstante no me funcionan correctamente los operadores logicos `<` y `>` que según tengo entendido en Batch son `LSS` y `GTR`.

Aquí mi código:

```
@echo off

title Edad

:main
cls
echo.
echo Introduce tu edad
echo.
set /p edad=

:eleccion
if %edad%==(0-12) (goto:niño) else(
    if %edad% LSS 18 (goto:adolecente) else(
        if %edad% LSS 45 (goto:adulto) else(
            if %edad% GTR 44 (goto:anciano) else(goto:error)
            )
        )
    )


:error
cls
echo.
msg * Error en valor de tu edad, por favor introduzca un número valido.
echo.
goto:main


:niño
echo Eres un niño
pause
exit

:adolecente
echo Eres un adolecente
pause
exit

:adulto
echo Eres un adulto
pause
exit

:anciano
echo Eres un anciano
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operadores para BAT (Windows)

- **EQU**, que es el equivalente a ==
- **NEQ**, Sirve para comprobar que No es Igual.
- **LSS**, Para verificar si el numero es Menor
- **LEQ**, Para verificar si es menor o igual.
- **GTR**, Si es mayor
- **GEQ**, Si es Mayor e igual.

El codigo seria mejor ponerlo asi:

```
if %edad% LEQ 0 goto:error
if %edad% LEQ 12 goto:chico
if %edad% LEQ 18 goto:adolecente
if %edad% LSS 45 goto:adulto
goto:anciano
```

El BAT es secuencial... simplemente si se cumple salta  (goto)... y no necesitas los ELSE !!